# Docker InfluxDB runs in UTC timezone

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timezone, influxdb

I try to run [influxdb](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) as a Docker container. I am using docker-compose for that:

```
influxdb:
  image: influxdb:1.7.7-alpine
  ports:
  - "8083:8083"
  - "8086:8086"
  - "8090:8090"
  volumes:
  - ./influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb
  networks:
    - mynet
  expose:
    - "8086"
  environment:
    TZ: Europe/Prague
```

The problem is the timezone. I don't know how to start InfluxDB in my local timezone, here you can see the problem:

```
[michal@motoko ~]$ LC_ALL=C date
Fri Aug 23 07:38:44 CEST 2019
[michal@motoko ~]$ LC_ALL=C influx -host 'localhost'
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.7.7
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.7
> use test Using database test
> insert test value=4 
> precision rfc3339
> select * from test
name: test
time                           value
----                           ----
2019-08-23T05:39:09.017460215Z 4
>
```

As you can see (correct) real time at my machine is "**07**:38:44" while timestamp stored in database is "**05**:39:09". I am in UTC+2 timezone.

Can InfluxDB in Docker run in my local timezone? I've tried to set `TZ` variable but InfluxDB probably needs `/etc/timezone`. I haven't found InfluxDB configuration parameter for that.

Or do I need to use `tz()` in every query? This works correctly:

```
> select * from test tz('Europe/Prague')
name: test
time                                value
----                                -----
2019-08-23T07:39:09.017460215+02:00 4
```

Comment: Hi Michal, have you seen [this](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3211)?

Comment: @RobertoGonçalves I think I did, I was hoping it is old information. :-) What is the common way to keep information about timezone of InfluxDB data? Do I need to maintain it somewhere externally?

Comment: I don't know if I got the question right...InfluxDB only has on it's core UTC.

Comment: @RobertoGonçalves I know, but you need to keep information about timezone somewhere, too. I guess you can do something like "INSERT timezone,appname=myapp value='Europe/Prague'" and keep it within the database this way.

Comment: Oh! Now I got it! Sure, you can keep your timezone information like this and then do a query to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments, InfluxDB timezone is [immutable](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3211) by default. But as you mentioned, you can set your timezone using *tz()* command.

A possible solution is store your timezone on InfluxDB and use it within your queries.

Answer (score 2):

In InfluxDB, the timestamp for your data point in nanosecond-precision Unix time. The timestamp is optional in line protocol. If you do not specify a timestamp for your data point InfluxDB uses the server’s local nanosecond timestamp in UTC.
So, when you insert the data, you don't specify the timestamp. The timestamp for the data was the real time on your machine.
But you can try with:

```
SELECT_clause [INTO_clause] FROM_clause [WHERE_clause] [GROUP_BY_clause] [ORDER_BY_clause] [LIMIT_clause] [OFFSET_clause] [SLIMIT_clause] [SOFFSET_clause] tz('<time_zone>')
```

The tz() clause returns the UTC offset for the specified timezone.

Or you can just change the default of your docker container.

Answer (score 0):

## InfluxDB 2.0+

In the docker-compose insert this:

```
environment:
  - TZ=Europe/Prague
```

Then inside container check if the variable `TZ` is present and date is changed. To check, connect to container `docker exec -it influxdb-container bash` and

```
date
Tue Jun 28 21:57:31 CEST 2022
```